# Divide Bootstrap navbar into two columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create two columns in my navbar. I use Bootstrap css.

All buttons are now lined out to the left. I would like to have the two last buttons to line out to the right... Is this possible and how do I do it ?

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" background-color: #eb8d22>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FOOD</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FOTO'S</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ARCHIEF</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PETER</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">VAKANTIEWONING</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version. Did you try the `pull-right` alignment class?

Comment: hey Isherwood, I added the bootstrap tag, sorry for that. Where do I add the pull-right alignment class? is it like: <li><a class="pull-right" href="#">PETER</a></li> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second `<ul>` list with 2 items is on the right side. Groet uit regio den haag.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #eb8d22;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarList" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle menu</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Site</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarList">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FOOD</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FOTO'S</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ARCHIEF</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">PETER</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">VAKANTIEWONING</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: MEGA DANK, het werkt :) Groeten terug uit OSLO